# How to convert ęąśćżńł TXT to PDF with enscript?

Tags: pdf, unicode, conversion, text, enscript

I have problem converting a file to PDF. I create the file with

```
echo ęąśćżńł > text
```

and convert:

```
enscript -O text -o - | ps2pdf - out.pdf
```

However, `out.pdf` has an encoding problem:

[image: screenshot of corrupted pdf file]

Comment: What kind of encoding problem is it that `out.pdf` has?

Comment: I'd have thought `iconv -t latin2 < text | enscript -X latin2 -o -` would work, but apparently not. Anybody knows why?

Comment: Replying to myself. It's [in this FAQ](http://www.markkurossi.com/genscript/FAQ.html). Probably not worth bothering with `enscript` and use `paps` or `a2ps` or other.

Comment: Paps not support headers and footers created with User.

Answer (score 6):

`enscript` just does not support `Unicode`. You need to use a different tool such as `paps` to convert text to `PostScript`. With `--header` option an output `.pdf` is similar to one produced with `enscript`:

```
$ paps text --header | ps2pdf - outheader.pdf
```

Comment: Paps not support headers and footers created with User.

Comment: What is `User`?

Comment: I'm a user and I would like created header and footer

Comment: I'm the author of paps. Please add a detailed feature request in the github repo, and I'll be happy to add this.

Answer (score 4):

I have had a better experience with the [u2ps](http://sourceforge.net/projects/u2ps.berlios) program written by Alex Suykov which produces much smaller PDF files using system Unicode fonts. This program is not in Ubuntu or Fedora; you have to compile it yourself. The usage is the same:

```
$ u2ps text.txt | ps2pdf - text.pdf
```

(Compared to u2ps, paps output is huge).

Comment: sure, guettli. corrected.